# Unable to install mongodb with chef server

Tags: mongodb, chef-infra

I'm having issues installing mongodb version `2.4.6` on an Amazon EC2 Linux with chef.

I'm using the popular mongodb [chef cookbook](https://github.com/edelight/chef-mongodb)

I've taken measures to ensure that my runlist specifies `recipe[mongodb::10gen_repo]` before `recipe[mongodb::default]`.

I am getting the following error though:

```
Recipe: mongodb::10gen_repo
  * yum_repository[10gen] action addRecipe: <Dynamically Defined Resource>
  * template[/etc/yum.repos.d/10gen.repo] action create (up to date)
  * execute[yum-makecache-10gen] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
  * ruby_block[yum-cache-reload-10gen] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
 (up to date)
Recipe: mongodb::default
  * package[mongo-10gen-server] action install
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'package[mongo-10gen-server]'
================================================================================


Chef::Exceptions::Exec
----------------------
 returned 1, expected 0


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mongodb/recipes/default.rb

 22: package node[:mongodb][:package_name] do
 23:   action :install
 24:   version node[:mongodb][:package_version]
 25: end
 26:



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/mongodb/recipes/default.rb:22:in `from_file'

package("mongo-10gen-server") do
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  package_name "mongo-10gen-server"
  version "2.4.6-mongodb_1"
  cookbook_name "mongodb"
  recipe_name "default"
end



[2013-12-26T09:22:05+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-12-26T09:22:05+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-12-26T09:22:05+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 5 resources updated
[2013-12-26T09:22:05+00:00] ERROR: package[mongo-10gen-server] (mongodb::default line 22) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Exec:  returned 1, expected 0
[2013-12-26T09:22:05+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Comment: Login to your machine you are trying to provision and try to install the package manually. It should also fail and you will see the error message - why.

Comment: thanks @DracoAter. it seems the package was unsigned, though actually instead of installing the package manually, i did this `sudo chef-client -l debug`

Answer (score 0):

Where have you defined `node[:mongodb][:package_name]`?

In order to use that cookbook, I believe you need to set that attribute.

Comment: hey @sethvargo. I have 
`default[:mongodb][:package_version] = "2.4.6-mongodb_1"` set in a wrapper cookbook attributes file. `node[:mongo][:package_name]`  is already set to `mongodb-server` by default by the mongodb cookbook